# How to read multiple yml config files from spring cloud config server

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I have seen that spring config server will read `${spring.application.name}.yml`. I have two files in my config server namely, `test.yml` and `test-dev.yml`. While i am running the config client, it is only picking either of the files. I want it to pick both the files at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: my "favorite chapter" - [Spring-Boot: 2. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config): It looks like you "only need" to add `dev` to `active.profiles` (on the "client";).

Answer (score 0):

This config goes into your client app:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <AppName>
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: <ConfigUrl>
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
      name: test,test-dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.